# Connecting multiple MC BUs to the same SF Org whlie using different record collection setting for each BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, connected-apps, marketing-cloud-connect

We have 3 business units in Marketing Cloud which should be connected to the same Salesforce ORG. Our MC account is already configured with multiple-org enabled.

We want each BU to have its own synchronized data extensions because each BU should have different record collection setting for each of the synced objects. For example: In BU A, account object should be populated with all account records who matches boolean_A to be 'true'. In BU B, account object should be populated with all account records who matches boolean_B to be 'true'. Reminding the object account pulled from the same SF ORG.

From talking to the SF support they advise to create a new MC API user and a new Salesforce system user dedicated to each BU connection (3 Salesforce system users connected to 3 Marketing Cloud API users).

Regarding setting up new Salesforce system users - there is no problem with that and we've already done it.

**The problem is how to configure multiple MC API users in the same ORG**. We are able to set only 1 MC API user in MC connect app within SF. Are we missing something? Is it even possbile to set more than 1 MC API user in the app? Perhaps it will be ok to connect the same MC API user to the 3 different SF system users to meet our needs?

Appreciate your help,

Barak

Comment: This configuration isn't supported. You can only connect with one integration user account per Org.

Comment: Hi Macca, thanks for your reply. When saying integration user are you referring to Salesforce system user or MC API user (or both?). If you are referring to MC API user - can you tell what are the implications to connect a single MC API user to multiple SF system users? Thanks

Comment: In addition will connecting the same MC API user to the 3 different SF system users should work? (creating different synchronized data for each business unit). Thanks

Comment: We also had this issue.. but haven't figured this out. Also couldn't find any relevant answers to this in the documentation